# Error message with strtotime function

Tags: php

I get the following error

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

With this function call:

```
 strtotime("-7 days", 2012-12-31);
```

But can't see any problems with it?

Comment: What are you expecting PHP to do with `2012-12-31`?

Comment: What do you want with 1969?

Comment: I am expecting to get the unix time which is 7 days before 2012-12-31. And I am getting the error message explained.

Comment: So replace the code with `'2012-12-24'`? :P

Comment: 2012-12-31 = 1969. You're subtracting three integers.

Comment: @Pedro Which is actually correct and should not cause the error mentioned, it just won't give the result the OP expects.

Comment: 1969 was, in all honesty, a rather good year as years go.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
echo  strtotime("-7 days  2012-12-31");
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is an `INT`, not a string.

Comment: Well, he *is* passing an `int`: 1969.

Answer (score 0):

`2012-12-31` isn't a date in PHP; you're doing a subtraction (the result of which is `1969`). You need to use `strtotime` to parse the date into an integer timestamp.

Fortunately, this can be combined with the `-7 days` string you're already using, like so:

```
strtotime("2012-12-31 -7 days");
```